# How to expand sidebars sub-menu to the correct size?

Tags: html, css

I have found an example sidebar and implemented it to fit my website but I got a problem with the CSS. It wants to expand at a set amount of height for the animation to be smooth (if I set the height to auto the animation is gone) but if I set the height to an actual value (124 px) it will open too much for the smaller menu items. Look at the picture below for clarification.

[image: Picture to clarify above text]

So to clarify the **question** - How do I make keep the animation while also just opening the sub-menu enough so that all of the items are shown (not more or less - like in the right picture)?

**CSS**

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: #A5B839;
    border-radius:10px 0px 0px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    margin: -15px auto;
    margin-left: -256px;
    margin-top: -58px;
}

.menu-item {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #A5B839;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 100%;
}
/*Menu Header Styles*/
.menu-item h4 {
  width: 97.8%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding:12px;
   background: #A5B839;

  /*Gradient*/
  background: #A5B839; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #A5B839 0%, #8f0222 44%, #6d0019 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#A5B839), color-stop(44%,#8f0222), color-stop(100%,#A5B839)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A5B839 0%,#A5B839 44%,#A5B839 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #A5B839 0%,#8f0222 44%,#A5B839 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #A5B839 0%,#A5B839 44%,#A5B839 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #A5B839 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#A5B839', endColorstr='#A5B839',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.menu-item h4:hover {  
  background-color: #fff; 

}
/*ul Styles*/
.menu-item ul{
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: -21px;
  margin-left: -20px;

  /*Animation*/
  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: height 1s ease;
       -o-transition: height 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: height 1s ease;
          transition: height 1s ease;
}

.menu-item ul a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #A5B839;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

/*li Styles*/
.menu-item li {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.menu-item:hover ul{
    height: 124px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="docSidebar" class="sidebar">                     
    <div class="menu-item alpha">
        <h4><a class="jumper" href="#Userguide">User guide</a></h4>                            
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <h4><a class="jumper" href="#Overview">Overview</a></h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#SOAP">SOAP</a></li>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#REST">REST</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <h4><a class="jumper" href="#CustomerOrder">Customer Order</a></h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#OrderHeader">OrderHeader</a></li>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#PartnerCustomer">Partner(Customer)</a></li>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#HaulierInfo">HaulierInfo</a></li>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#OrderLine">OrderLine</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <h4><a class="jumper" href="#ItemsProducts">Items (Products)</a></h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#Item">Item</a></li>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#ItemAlias">ItemAlias</a></li>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#Dimension">Dimension</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <h4><a class="jumper" href="#CustomerB2B">Customer (B2B)</a></h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#Customer">Customer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <h4><a class="jumper" href="#Suppliers">Suppliers</a></h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#Supplier">Supplier</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <h4><a class="jumper" href="#PurchaseOrder">Purchase Order</a></h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#PurchaseOrderHeader">Purchase Order Header</a></li>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#PurchaseOrderLine">Purchase Order Line</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <h4><a class="jumper" href="#ShipmentOrder">Shipment Order</a></h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#Order">Order</a></li>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#ShippedPackages">ShippedPackages</a></li>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#ShippedItems">ShippedItems</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <h4><a class="jumper" href="#Appendix">Appendix</a></h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#Appendix1">Sample order creation in JQuery over REST-API</a></li>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#Appendix2">Sample item creation C#</a></li>
            <li><a class="jumper" href="#Appendix3">Sample Shipment Transaction</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <h4><a class="jumper" href="#top"><br />Back To Top</a></h4>
    </div>                            
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: #A5B839;
    border-radius:10px 0px 0px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    margin: -15px auto;
    margin-left: -256px;
    margin-top: -58px;
}

.menu-item {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #A5B839;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 100%;
}
/*Menu Header Styles*/
.menu-item h4 {
  width: 97.8%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding:12px;
   background: #A5B839;

  /*Gradient*/
  background: #A5B839; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #A5B839 0%, #8f0222 44%, #6d0019 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#A5B839), color-stop(44%,#8f0222), color-stop(100%,#A5B839)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A5B839 0%,#A5B839 44%,#A5B839 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #A5B839 0%,#8f0222 44%,#A5B839 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #A5B839 0%,#A5B839 44%,#A5B839 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #A5B839 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#A5B839', endColorstr='#A5B839',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.menu-item h4:hover {  
  background-color: #fff; 

}
/*ul Styles*/
.menu-item ul{
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  max-height: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: -21px;
  margin-left: -20px;

  /*Animation*/
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: max-height 1s ease;
       -o-transition: max-height 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: max-height 1s ease;
          transition: max-height 1s ease;
}

.menu-item ul a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #A5B839;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

/*li Styles*/
.menu-item li {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.menu-item:hover ul{
    max-height: 124px;
}
```

Instead of animating `height` we animate `max-height` and just use the same values. Now the height should animate from 0px to whatever height the content requires.

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I was looking for.